# Sinatra - downstream app not set

Tags: heroku, routes, sinatra, thin

I'm getting this strange error: `downstream app not set`

However my app is responding and working well.

I've checked - and I've not found any requests to undefined routes.
(Maybe there is some tools to debug that)

Checked Google too.

Please help - how to remove this error.

Log:

```
00:52:51 web.1  | started with pid 13052
00:52:59 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013 00:52:59] "GET /manage HTTP/1.1" 200 5046 0.3123
00:52:59 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013 00:52:59] "GET /javascripts/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0138
00:52:59 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013 00:52:59] "GET /javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0121
00:52:59 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013 00:52:59] "GET /javascripts/jquery.capty.custom.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0075
00:52:59 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013 00:52:59] "GET /stylesheets/articles_grid.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0131
00:52:59 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2013 00:52:59] "GET /javascripts/articles_grid.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0008
00:53:05 web.1  | RuntimeError - downstream app not set:
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:688:in `forward'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `route_missing'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:719:in `route!'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:715:in `route!'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:715:in `route!'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:843:in `dispatch!'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:644:in `block in call!'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:808:in `instance_eval'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:808:in `block in invoke'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:808:in `catch'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:808:in `invoke'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:644:in `call!'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:629:in `call'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/Projects/*******************/app.rb:22:in `call'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `call'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `block in pre_process'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `catch'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `pre_process'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/thin-1.2.11/bin/thin:6:in `'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/thin:19:in `load'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/thin:19:in `'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
00:53:05 web.1  |  /home/blacktea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'
```

Here is layout.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "content-type"}
      %title The Project 
      %script{:src => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
      %script{:src => "/javascripts/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
      %script{:src => "/javascripts/jquery.masonry.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
      %script{:src => "/javascripts/jquery.capty.custom.js", :type => "text/javascript"}

      %link{:rel => :stylesheet, :href => "/stylesheets/articles_grid.css", :type => "text/css"}
      %script{:src => "/javascripts/articles_grid.js", :type => "text/javascript"}

  %body{:onload => "framesetsize(800, 1000)", :style => "overlflow: hidden;"}
    %script{:src => "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
    :javascript
      FB.init({
        appId : '#{ @app['id'] }',
         cookie : true
       });
    =yield
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my dev browsers (Chrome) was constantly requesting for /favicon.ico

```
get "/favicon.ico" do
end
```

Solved the problem